Is it possible to use csf with BibTeXU?
I'm from the Persian/Farsi LaTeX user community. We should use bibtex8 for compilation and producing references in Persian/Farsi documents. To incorporate a different sorting order, we use a csf file with the bibtex8 -W -c cp1256fa % command. I want to replace bibtex8 with bibtexu. How do I incorporate a csf file with bibtexu?
Update: I've discovered that BibTeXU utilizes the ICU (International Components for Unicode) library. Is it feasible to develop a customized sorting algorithm with the ICU library and integrate it for use with bibtexu?

last time I looked at bibtexu (around 3 years ago when updating the relevant chapter of the LaTeX companion) it was completly buggy and unusable. A bit work has been done on it in the meantime by someone from the Japanese TeX community, but its current maintainance status is unclear and there is basically no documentation. Personally I would use biblatex and biber. They properly support unicode and various sortings.

Thank you for your response, @UlrikeFischer. Considering the existing issues, if I still wish to use bibtexu, what options are available to integrate a customized sorting algorithm for use with bibtexu?

I have no idea. As I said, when I last tried it is was so buggy that not even basic things worked properly so I not even started to look for special options (which wasn't possible anyway due to the lack of documentation). Contact the maintainer and ask.
